# how to split an array from ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call that has 2 objects being brought back that has other objects contained within it. I am trying to split off the first object and string together all of the objects into a string array.

```
function first(){
      $.ajax({
     url: '/main/sub',
     data: { var1: var1, var2: var2, var3:var3 }
     }).done(function(results){
     if (results != ""){
         var test = populateSource(JSON.parse(results)); // this gets everything back
         }
     }
}
```

So the variables that get brought back are Apps and SubApps in which Apps contains 10 objects that they each have objects within it.

For example, it returns:

Apps: Array [100]
SubApps: Array [3]

If you click on Array[100] it returns:
0: Object
1: Object... with the data inside each object

I need a variable to split off the Apps array and just show the data inside like:

```
"[{"cycle":1, "cycle2":2, ...}]"
```

Comment: What's the question/problem? Also, you shouldn't need to `JSON.parse` the result as jQuery will do that for you - assuming you're returning valid JSON. It may also help if you could show an example of the result in the question

Comment: You want to turn an object into string array? What does that even mean?

Comment: updated with the information

Comment: @Keith have you reviewed the answer yet, still haven't gotten any feedback sadly :(

Comment: Yes I did. I apologize, I thought I posted what I came up with. I just had to index the result, kind of like what you did so it would be datasource: results[0] which gives me the first object showing me everything inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i = 0; i <= results.length; i++) {
    if(results.length > i) {
        var data1 = results[i].var1;
        var data2 = results[i].var2;
    }
}
```

that's a basic for loop to get the data split, you just need to match the values to the values you receive back.

P.S. put this in the .done and not outside of it.